Given Houthis' proven ability to disrupt shipping, how does the US hope to stop the PRC from doing something like that to Taiwan?
Assuming the PRC goes 'all out' on an economic blockade of Taiwan, including sinking by any available means any ship that goes close to Taiwan, how does the US hope to prevent that, given e.g. the recent experience with Houthis' ability to disrupt commercial shipping, with a fraction of the military resources that the PRC has?
(It looks like more than half of Taiwan's shipping is through a port on the mainland-facing side of the island--"Kaohsiung, responsible for 57% of Taiwan’s maritime imports and most of its energy imports".)

Downvotes are silly, this is eminently answerable.

@Allure Not that I'm saying this deserves to be at -3, but "eminently answerable" is not mutually exclusive with "does not show any research effort" or "not useful".

@F1Krazy Sure, but the four close votes (which are more likely to come from people who downvoted the question) all give "cannot be verified ...".

Yes, but that has nothing to do with your original comment about the downvotes, which is what I was responding to.

Is there any evidence China is planning a blockade of Taiwan, or how that blockade would be implemented? There are many things the US could do in response, but they would depend on the precise nature of the blockade - if China repeatedly and deliberately sank American ships the response would be very different to if they flashed some lights at Taiwanese merchant vessels or protested to the Taiwanese government. Hence, this isn't really answerable as it stands.

I think the question should be reopened but mainly because the answer is simple and clear: geography. The Houthi's and Taiwan are not remotely similar geographically so the initial assumption is plain false and should be recorded.

I'm not sure what the motivation of the question is. A blockade is an act of war so the  US has entire navy to conduct counter operations since they will be at war.

@uberhaxed It's not an act of war against the US. See Ukraine. Or even the Houthi attack on that Palau-flagged vessel--officially an ally of the US. I'd be impressed if no red lines will be drawn and some idea of 'limited war' in such circumstances isn't already sketched by the think tanks at least.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever The Houthis are not a sovereign nation, comparing anything to them is disingenuous.

@uberhaxed: LOL, keep telling yourself that. (And see 9/11 aftermath.) Apparently the new word for limited war (at sea) is "cumulative strategy". https://www.usni.org/magazines/proceedings/2024/february/houthi-rebels-cry-havoc-and-let-slip-drones-war

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Congress cannot declare war on the Houthis so the steps the US can take against a terrorist group are different than those they can take e.g. against China.

Voted to Close - You are inviting speculation for a future hypothetical event.

The true plans of the US (and the PRC) are of course classified. But there are studies by non-military researchers about how such a conflict might be fought. Some of the researchers are in "think tanks" affilated with government and military, so their thoughts might be seen as indicative how their side might possibly fight.
If the PRC decides to blockade the ROC with an exclusion zone and missile fire, and if the US decides to fight (they reserve a little ambiguity over that, but indications are they would), then the US would attack Chinese launchers in the region and China would likely attack US bases in the region. The US is likely the stronger power overall, but it might not be able to concentrate all forces in the Pacific.

RAND study, nine years ago, comparing the US and PRC including a ROC scenario.
RAND study, last year, about the ROC ability to resist.
RAND study, last year, about possible Great Power wars, including China scenarios.


This source gives a nice analysis of what might happen if China attempted a blockade of Taiwan. A short summary is below.

China could definitely do this, and it would be very painful for Taiwan.
However, a blockade of Taiwan would not necessarily lead to Taiwan surrendering in the short term. That's because Taiwan produces a lot of food.
The main import that's not easily replaced is energy. Taiwan produces some energy locally, but not a lot of it; rationing would surely be forced, with associated economic consequences. But economic devastation has historically not forced besieged cities to surrender.
Taiwan is very capable of retaliating against China for such a blockade. Yes, China can stop ships from reaching Taiwan, but equally, Taiwan can also stop ships from reaching China. China's busiest ports (Shanghai, Ningbo-Zhoushan, Shenzhen, Qingdao, and Guangzhou) are all within missile range from Taiwan.

The upshot is that if China is serious about forcing Taiwan to submit with a blockade, it must be ready to shoot down civilian planes with Taiwanese cargo, and it must be ready to fire upon ships & submarines that are attempting to thwart the blockade. In other words, either the Chinese blockade is ineffective, or it escalates to war. For a Chinese blockade to have teeth, it must first mobilize its military and threaten to back up its blockade with a full-scale invasion. Therefore, "how will the US stop a Chinese blockade?" is effectively the same question as "how will the US stop a Chinese invasion?".

I'm not sure I really buy the very last bit, but the rest of the analysis is interesting. Of some note though, most of those Chine ports are pretty far, and only the handful of indigenously developed Taiwanese missiles (not US supplied ones) can reach them. So the counterstrike would probably be limited, and China might be able to shoot down many of those missiles. (Also, detecting ships hundreds of miles away is fairly challenging, if e.g. they turn off the AIS.) But yeah, it's a gamble China wouldd have to take.

At least a decade ago, some Western thinkers thought far more likely that the US would manage to impose a far more crippling blockade on China:

By prosecuting a naval blockade, the United States would leverage China’s intense dependence on foreign trade—particularly oil—to debilitate the Chinese state.

A strategy not unlike that used against Japan right before and in WW2. That also assumes the US would win naval & air supremacy against China, like it did against Japan.
OTOH, the same piece discusses that (unlike Japan) China can ultimately import oil overland from Russia, and goes into a discussion how much could China import/substitute that way.

Is oil imported much over land between Russia and China for example? I thought that gas is transported a lot over land but oil mostly by ship.
